# How to stream video download via api with bearer token? - Laravel, Vue.js, HTML5

Tags: vue.js, html5-video, bearer-token, laravel-6

I'm following this guide to return a video download response: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

I want to do this through an API call, where the user is identified via a bearer token.

How should the ajax call look like, so I get this response at the same time that I'm "injecting" it into the HTML5 video src?

I've tried the below

**Controller**

```
$path = storage_path('app/videos/'.$request->input('code').'.mp4');

$file = File::get($path);
$type = File::mimeType($path);

$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);

return $response;
```

**Javascript**

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/user/video?code=2y101QBU5kxvPpaqGFFI16ZPeWg6jxXOQtwnTBvM61OjgrPACE2VA2y100oygu8kajpnp9i6U6ug28oC0dNnFxd5rNxvZeupBVedbzFgPo62i',
        headers: {
            "Authorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjZlY2NkYzI4NzZlYmFiMjFhNTA5NTZiZGFkMGI4Mjk0ZjM2NTExOWM1YTU1NjI5MzQ5Y2QzY2QxMmZkZWM4NDE1YTEyYjUzMzFlMDA4OTEwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNmVjY2RjMjg3NmViYWIyMWE1MDk1NmJkYWQwYjgyOTRmMzY1MTE5YzVhNTU2MjkzNDljZDNjZDEyZmRlYzg0MTVhMTJiNTMzMWUwMDg5MTAiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njc0OTU1NTgsIm5iZiI6MTU2NzQ5NTU1OCwiZXhwIjoxNTk5MTE3OTU4LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.MSxiEo-UswoKS5XqfezR4MDDgUvnsQuSwbM_IawIpERqNncY4F51H_mJ-chrIuA9cKcurj79Qpop2MNxyGTVSmT07DYd9jApXV3ayMbCmLLLZMJMIDsXP7_g9v-0ogBc-jYPkVFuXdzrxtmuOfi6XwUPDKq9JEhl9sB3tpqW2x3rUbPGE--vQvToXBMia8l9y5-2er6M2Rrbz0fit912fi_5LxjOkbm2MRCwhoFIhqPR_2VdGH733CmpY_pyIQs6XPbssIt7PssOryvreaQZUsq1XrUk82QjuZpDELufWnr1F2foc9UeLQaGthIDY4RNNR1nd4n7ZuG-FrKfnzC3eq2nfF9wpG3o8xMHoaOMYl1bbZJkE41BMPagwIv8F8KJwSJZpjxrq9LgTWs9-WVUbBFnf85ieER5-ltKM5vC8uwTYcETLxQzEBC_qf-durUC07740qf5r-oIlAfVQmksZgrG7XgtAkZqcZEEeiVsWE_JOcFiv0lj4IOcX6NhZR2RDP_reTTauOxxqt56VX0weib3F0Ub1DKe2ATbDBG9m7bCIRSIYUf58HXthHmjQKJ4ANxYxSwV3gcJsOodUsZTg9e5sjwGwBtIXrNybrFswQlE76kGyQ4-L1R6XTHFmKIWS0ac-Xk4RAmWoBZxDn-RNw0YAfsGtzj4XimJKRx36dM",
        }
    }).done(function(data) { 
        var video = $('#myvideo')[0];
        video.src = data;
        video.load();
        video.play();
    });
```

But I get the error below in the console

```
(index):106 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
(anonymous) @   (index):106
c   @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
l   @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
load (async)        
send    @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   (index):96
```